# Replacing part of a URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four url's, that follow the example format below;

- http://br91.0--a.justteachit.local/resource1
- http://br91.0--a.teachers.local/resource1

From a button click I want the user to be able to alternate between the four different url's, without the '/resource1' (path) part of the url changing or the page changing (the page can reload of course). I would just create 4 standard hyperlinks but I have many 'paths'.

i.e /resource1 to /resource9999

The code I have so far is:

```
 var url = window.location.toString();
window.location = url.replace(br91.0--a.justteachit, 
'br91.0--a.teachers.local');
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `url.replace(br91.0--a.justteachit, 
'br91.0--a.teachers.local');` should be: `url.replace('br91.0--a.justteachit', 
'br91.0--a.teachers.local');` (note the quotes) unless you're doing some very strange maths with variables (you're not, you're really not; it's a syntax error).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [location api](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Location):

```
var url = window.location;
var newDomain = 'br91.0--a.teachers.local/':
var reloadUrl = newDomain + url.pathname + url.search;

window.location = reloadUrl;
```